# nhibernate getsession call

Tags: nhibernate

HI,

For a web application I really don't need any fancy transaction support etc.

If I just make by call to get session to do first look in the Request.ITems, if its not their then I call it and store it in the request.items collection, would that be enough really?

Answer (score 0):

You could, but then you would surely be violating [SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  I would at the very least put the creation of the session in an HttpModule or Global.asax then wrap some sort of locator around getting the session out of the request context.